# How can I pass serializer.data into create function without using save function in views django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**views.py**

```
def productslist(request):
    products = Products.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products}
    return render(request,'productslist.html',context)

def productsform(request):
    return render(request,'productscreate.html')
    @api_view(['GET','POST'])
    def products_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        product = Products.objects.all()
        serializer = Productserialize(product,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = Productserialize(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        def create(serializer):
            return Products.objects.create(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors)

@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
def products_detail(request, pk):
  
    products = Products.objects.get(pk=pk)

  
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = Productserialize(products)
        return Response(serializer.data)
  
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = Productserialize(products, data=request.data)
  
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

In views.py I have done create function but it is not working not saving data
I want to save serializer data using create function
I want to pass serializer.data into create function in post method api

**serializer.py**

```
class Productserialize(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    image = serializers.FileField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Products.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: you are not calling the create function. it is just created

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [ListCreateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) and use a [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) instead of a `Serializer`.

```py
# Serializer
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'image')
        model = Product


# View
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView

class ProductListCreate(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

`ListCreateAPIView` handle GET to list and POST to create new objects, you don't need to override anything else.

Comment: But I want to use serializer not model serializer and I  want to pass serializer.data into create function

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `ModelSerializer`? The `create`method is already handled there. Anyways, if you call `seriliazer.save()`, that will trigger the `create` method of your serializer if the pk is None.

Comment: Because that was the task for me thats y I want to use serializer and i want to do serializer.data in create function

Answer (score 0):

you can try to call it

```
if serializer.is_valid():
        def create(serializer):
            return Products.objects.create(serializer.data)
        crerate(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I have done this code but data is not saving in database

Comment: Please help me to solve this